# небесплодным / не бесплодным, а весьма результативным

Tags: орфография

РАН говорит – здесь-таки: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77, – что прилагательные с первой частью *небес-* никогда не пишутся отдельно с *не-*. Неужели это правило работает-таки даже в этом предложении?

Дедов-Ванин совет немедля появился: «Надо создать газету, которая будет иметь название „Назло не сделанное действие, которое оказалось **небесплодным / не бесплодным, а весьма результативным**“».

Comment: Где вы видели слово "никогда"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В зависимости от смысла возможны **две записи**:

1. **Напрасный — результативный**

*Назло не сделанное действие, которое оказалось **не бесплодным**  (= напрасным), а весьма **результатИвным**.*

2. Результативный **отчасти** — **весьма** результативный

Назло не сделанное действие, которое оказалось **не небесплодным**  (=отчасти результативным), а **весьмА** результативным.

3. В заданном предложении речь идет об общем результате действия, поэтому подходит **первый вариант**:

*Назло не сделанное действие, которое оказалось **не бесплодным**  (= напрасным), а весьма **результатИвным**.*

Здесь нет несоответствия правилам, просто по смыслу нужно использовать слово "**бесплодный"**, но не слово  "небесплодный".

**БЕСПЛОДНЫЙ.** 4. Не приносящий желаемых результатов; бесполезный, напрасный. Б-ые усилия, поиски, сожаления.

**НЕБЕСПЛОДНЫЙ**. Приносящий некоторые плоды, результаты; небесполезный. Н-ые хлопоты. Н-ая командировка.